Triggering CodePipeline stage on specific time everyday using aws-cdk
I have a use-case where I have 2 codePipeline stages:

DEV Stage
QA Stage

I want when my code merge on master branch, codePipeline DEV stage will trigger automatically but after its completion, it not goes immediately on QA stage. It holds on DEV.
Suppose I want to trigger QA Stage 12 PM IST every-day so, QA Stage will trigger automatically 12PM IST everyday independently. How can we do this please help me there.
I want to implement this with help of AWS-CDK in serverless manner
This is my lambda function file:
import { CodePipeline } from "aws-sdk";
import { Handler } from "aws-lambda";

// Initialize CodePipeline client
const codePipeline = new CodePipeline();

interface LambdaEvent {
  pipelineName: string;
  approvalToken: string;
  stageName: string;
  actionName: string;
}

export const handler: Handler<LambdaEvent> = async (event) => {
  const { pipelineName, stageName, actionName } = event;

  try {
    const pipelineState = await codePipeline
      .getPipelineState({ name: pipelineName })
      .promise();

    if (!pipelineState.stageStates) {
      throw new Error("No stage states found for the pipeline.");
    }

    // Find the specific stage
    const stage = pipelineState.stageStates.find(
      (stage) => stage.stageName === stageName,
    );

    if (!stage || !stage.actionStates) {
      throw new Error(
        `Stage '${stageName}' not found or no action states available.`,
      );
    }

    // Find the specific action within the stage
    const action = stage.actionStates.find(
      (actionState) => actionState.actionName === actionName,
    );

    if (!action || !action.latestExecution || !action.latestExecution.token) {
      throw new Error(
        `Action '${actionName}' not found or no approval token available.`,
      );
    }

    const approvalToken = action.latestExecution.token;

    const approvalParams = {
      pipelineName,
      stageName,
      actionName,
      result: {
        status: "Approved", // 'Approved' or 'Rejected'
        summary: "Stage approved by Lambda function",
      },
      token: approvalToken,
    };

    console.log("Approval Params:", approvalParams);

    // Submit the approval result
    const response = await codePipeline
      .putApprovalResult(approvalParams)
      .promise();
    console.log("Approval result submitted:", response);

    return { message: "Stage approval submitted successfully." };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error submitting approval result:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

This is my cdk-stack file:
import * as cdk from "aws-cdk-lib";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { Pipeline, Artifact } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline";
import {
  GitHubSourceAction,
  CodeBuildAction,
  ManualApprovalAction,
} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline-actions";
import { Project, BuildSpec } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-codebuild";
import {
  Effect,
  Policy,
  PolicyDocument,
  PolicyStatement,
  Role,
  ServicePrincipal,
} from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam";
import { NodejsFunction } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs";
import { Runtime } from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda";
import { CfnResource, Duration } from "aws-cdk-lib";

export class CdkPocStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    // GitHub repository details
    const githubRepoOwner = "owner";
    const githubRepoName = "sample-repo";
    const githubBranch = "master";
    const githubOAuthToken = cdk.SecretValue.secretsManager("token");

    // Create a pipeline
    const pipeline = new Pipeline(this, "MyCodePipeline", {
      pipelineName: "MyCodePipeline",
    });

    // Artifacts
    const sourceOutput = new Artifact();
    const devBuildOutput = new Artifact();

    // Define the source action
    const sourceAction = new GitHubSourceAction({
      actionName: "GitHub_Source",
      owner: githubRepoOwner,
      repo: githubRepoName,
      oauthToken: githubOAuthToken,
      output: sourceOutput,
      branch: githubBranch,
    });

    // Add source stage
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Source",
      actions: [sourceAction],
    });

    // Define the DEV stage
    const devProject = new Project(this, "DevBuildStageProject", {
      buildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: "0.2",
        phases: {
          install: {
            runtimeVersions: {
              nodejs: 18,
            },
            commands: ["npm install"],
          },
        },
        artifacts: {
          files: "**/*",
        },
      }),
    });

    const devAction = new CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: "Dev_Stage_Build",
      project: devProject,
      input: sourceOutput,
      outputs: [devBuildOutput],
    });

    // Add DEV stage
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "DEV",
      actions: [devAction],
    });

    // Define the QA stage
    const qaProject = new Project(this, "QaBuildStageProject", {
      buildSpec: BuildSpec.fromObject({
        version: "0.2",
        phases: {
          install: {
            runtimeVersions: {
              nodejs: 18,
            },
            commands: ["npm install"],
          },
        },
        artifacts: {
          files: "**/*",
        },
      }),
    });

    const qaAction = new CodeBuildAction({
      actionName: "QA_Stage_Test",
      project: qaProject,
      input: sourceOutput,
      runOrder: 2, // Ensures QA stage doesn't run immediately after DEV
    });

    const manualApprovalAction = new ManualApprovalAction({
      actionName: "Approve_QA",
    });

    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Pre_QA_Approval",
      actions: [manualApprovalAction],
    });

    // Add QA stage to pipeline (but set it to not auto-trigger)
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "QA",
      actions: [qaAction],
    });

    // Create IAM Role for Lambda
    const lambdaRole = new Role(this, "LambdaExecutionRole", {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
    });

    lambdaRole.addManagedPolicy({
      managedPolicyArn:
        "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole",
    });

    lambdaRole.addToPolicy(
      new PolicyStatement({
        actions: ["codepipeline:PutApprovalResult"],
        resources: [pipeline.pipelineArn],
        effect: Effect.ALLOW,
      }),
    );

    // Lambda to trigger the QA stage
    const oneOffLambda = new NodejsFunction(this, "OneOffLambda", {
      entry: "lib/lambda/qa-stage-trigger.ts", // Lambda code should be in this file
      handler: "index.handler",
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_20_X,
      timeout: Duration.seconds(10),
      environment: {
        PIPELINE_NAME: pipeline.pipelineName,
      },
    });

    // IAM Role for AWS Scheduler to invoke the Lambda
    const schedulerRole = new Role(this, "schedulerRole", {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal("scheduler.amazonaws.com"),
    });

    // Policy to allow Scheduler to invoke the Lambda
    const invokeLambdaPolicy = new Policy(this, "invokeLambdaPolicy", {
      document: new PolicyDocument({
        statements: [
          new PolicyStatement({
            actions: ["lambda:InvokeFunction"],
            resources: [oneOffLambda.functionArn],
            effect: Effect.ALLOW,
          }),
        ],
      }),
    });

    schedulerRole.attachInlinePolicy(invokeLambdaPolicy);

    // AWS Scheduler rule to run at 9:00 PM IST (3:30 PM UTC)
    new CfnResource(this, "oneOffSchedule", {
      type: "AWS::Scheduler::Schedule",
      properties: {
        Name: "oneOffSchedule",
        Description: "Runs a schedule every day at 10:10 PM IST",
        FlexibleTimeWindow: { Mode: "OFF" },
        ScheduleExpression: "cron(15 17 * * ? *)", // 10:10 PM IST (4:40 PM UTC)
        Target: {
          Arn: oneOffLambda.functionArn,
          RoleArn: schedulerRole.roleArn,
          Input: JSON.stringify({
            pipelineName: "TimeBoxCodePipeline",
            approvalToken: "your-approval-token",
            stageName: "Pre_QA_Approval",
            actionName: "Approve_QA",
          }),
        },
      },
    });
  }
}

